# MobX observable with dynamic data

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have the following class

```
export default class BaseStore {
  @observable model ;

  @action updateStore(propertyName, newValue) {
    this.model[propertyName] = newValue;
  }
}
```

In child classes I add layers to the observable model, such as :

```
model.payment.type = 'credit card'
```

My react component doesn't render automatically when this happen, it does however, if I has a top level data such as:

```
model.Type = 'CreditCard'
```

I am new to MobX, and read that I need to make use of map() but I am unable to find a decent example that explain how to use it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'In child classes I add layers to the observable model'? Could you please share exact pieces of code that add _layers_ to the model?

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the keys that the `model` will have, you can just initialize them with a `null` value, and the `observer` components will re-render.

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/foqidizuri/edit?js,output))**

```
class BaseStore {
  @observable model = {
    type: null
  };

  @action updateStore(propertyName, newValue) {
    this.model[propertyName] = newValue;
  }
}

const baseStore = new BaseStore();

@observer
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => baseStore.model.type = 'CreditCard', 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return <div> { baseStore.model.type } </div>;
  }
}
```

If you don't know all the keys of `model` beforehand, you can use a [**map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html) like you said:

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gomuvateso/edit?js,output))**

```
class BaseStore {
  model = observable.map({});

  @action updateStore(propertyName, newValue) {
    this.model.set(propertyName, newValue);
  }
}

const baseStore = new BaseStore();

@observer
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const key = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      const val = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
      baseStore.updateStore(key, val);
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return <div> 
      { baseStore.model.entries().map(e => <div> {`${e[0]} ${e[1]}` } </div>) } 
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: My issue is with deeper items, such as :
model.input.card.number  // as an example
this case doesnt trigger the "Render" function

Comment: I start with just model and I want in run time to starting adding items such as this hierarchy: model.Payment.CreditCard.Amount. And I want my render to invoke when I change the amount although the original observer didn't have this item until later in the lifecycle of the program.